# How the assignment operator in container_of() macro is working

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I have tried to work with the container_of macro in linux kernel.

what I get by google is as follow

```
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)

#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
({ const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
 (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})

#define CONT(prt, type, mem) container_of((prt), type, mem)

struct test {
 int a;
};

struct m {
 int b;
 struct test t;
 int c;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 /* existing structure */
 struct m *ma;
 ma = malloc(sizeof(struct m));
 ma->t.a = 5;
 ma->b = 3;
 /* pointer to existing entry */    
 struct test *te = &ma->t;

 struct m *m = CONT(te, struct m, t);

 printf("m->b = %d\n", m->b);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

o/p
m->b = 3

but I am having the doubt in the assignment of *m .I have tried following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int x = (int k = 9;k-2;);
        printf("x= %d k = %d",x,k);
}
```

o/p

```
one.c:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘k’
one.c:5: error: expected expression before ‘;’ token
one.c:6: error: ‘k’ undeclared (first use in this function)
one.c:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
one.c:6: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

If this assignment is wrong here then how  it is working in container of macro.what is the difference in above two.(I know one is macro and other is normal declaration but after macro expansion both will look same)

Note:Excuse me as this may be a simple but I am not able to figure it out.

kinldy give some solution to my dobut.

Comment: What do you think you want to do with this `int x = (int k = 9;k-2;);`?

Comment: I want the value 7 should be assigned to x.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this :`int k=9; int x=k-2;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using special gcc features, namely block expressions `({    })`. These allow to to have a object definition inside an expression. The last statement in this construct determines the value of the block expression.

So you missed the additional `{ }` inside the expression for your test case.

Also:

- there is no assignment in that macro, but only initialization of the local variable
- the `typeof` operator in there also is a gcc extension

Comment: Exactly what I want ..Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding my answer to this question because I got some point .It may help other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x = ({int k = 9;k-2;});
printf("x = %d",x);

 }
```

o/p 
x = 7

As Jens said above its all true I have missed the `{ }` but addition to that ,I am printing the value of k which is not correct as all the value created with in the `({ })` are temporary and will delete as soon as the value of expression is evaluated.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs